# Rspec expect with object validate values

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am doing tests and I want to assert that an object that goes to a dependency contains the values I am expecing. For this I have the next piece of code:

```rb
foo = Foo.new(1, 10, 0)
    
dependency = double
expect(dependency).to receive(:function).with(foo)
```

But this fails, obviously, as in the code I do a `Foo.new ...` so this object is not the same as the one in the logic. It makes sense, and I get an error like the next:

```
#<Double (anonymous)> received :function with unexpected arguments
expected: (#<Foo:0x00000000001 @value_1=1, @value_2=10, @value_3=0>)
got: (#<Foo:0x00000000002 @value_1=1, @value_2=10, @value_3=0>)
```

But the values on the object are the same.

Is there any way of validating only the values and not the object itself?

I can do the following, and it works, but this scenario has just three properties. On a bigger object, this will be a bit of a mess.

```rb
expect(dependency).to receive(:function).with(having_attributes(value_1: 1, value_2: 10, value_3: 0)
```

can this validation be done out of the box?

Thanks.

EDIT1: This is the code that I am trying to test

```rb
foo = Foo.new(value_1, value_2, value_3)
@dependency.function(foo)
```

Comment: Could you show the code that is a subject of testing, please? The question sounds like a coupling problem, with the hardcoded dependency that cannot be mocked easily. Often you can workaround this by using `expect_any_instance_of(...).to have_received(...)` etc, but this is discouraged to some extent (it is better to invest some time for refactoring so the proper dependencies are injected instead...)

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov just did, thanks. I don't think the issue is the `expect`; there is no problem on the dependency itself but in the parameter on the function (the `with`)

Comment: There will be a line after that failure that says "compared using..." most likely this says "compared using ==". Knowing this you can define `Foo#==` to compare `Foo` objects in a manner that suits your needs e.g. `def ==(other); return false unless other.is_a?(Foo); #determine how to compare Foo Objects here; end;`

Comment: @engineersmnky I don't have that line, but I do completely understand what you mean, seems like the only way I have to do this is to update the `==` operator? I think I prefer the current `having_attributes` as I would like to have something only for the test, that does not affect the actual code.  Thanks.